# MIPS Assembly Memory Addressing "Pseudo Direct Addressing"

Tags: assembly, mips

Could anyone explain how does Pseudo Direct Addressing work in MIPS?

[image]

I don't really get how does using the last 4 bits from the PC (Program Counter) fit into the picture?

Suppose I want to goto Address

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100
```

And my PC looks like `0101 ...`

Then I can't? Because I will need the last 4 bits to look like 0101 instead? So it will somewhat be relative to PC too?

Comment: Why the vote to close?  In general, microcontroller programming questions have been allowed in this forum.  Note under RELATED in the right sidebar the number of MIPS questions.

Comment: @tcrosley and the close voter - Please submit your opinion at [this Meta discussion](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/852/where-do-we-draw-the-line-for-code-being-on-or-off-topic)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MIPS pseudo-direct addressing takes the upper four bits of the program counter, concatenated with the 26 bits of the direct address from the instruction, *concatenated with two bits of 0 0:*

```
PC31...PC28    IM25...IM00    0    0
```

which creates a complete 32-bit address.  This format is used by the J-type instructions, j and jal.  Since the upper 4 bits of the PC are used, this constrains the jump target to anywhere within the current 256 MB block of code (1/16 of the total 4 GB address space).  To jump anywhere within the 4 GB space, the R-type instructions jr and jalr are used, where the complete 32-bit target address is specified in a register.

The reason for forcing the bottom two bits to 0 is that all instruction addresses in MIPS are 32-bit word aligned, so you can never have a target address of a jump instruction with the two bits anything other than 0 0.

Comment: So i suppose the 256MB comes from 2^28?

Comment: @jiewmeng, correct.  The top 4 bits, coming from the program counter, select 1 of 16 "banks" of 256 MB, and the low 28 bits select a byte within that bank.  But as previously mentioned, only bytes with an address modulo 4 == 0 are allowed since the bottom two bits are always 0 0.